# Why do i need to specify constructor argument as nullable generic type?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm trying to make OK() to call ApiResponse constructor. When I give null to ApiResponse constructor argument, it shows error that type mismatches.

If I change data type to T? it works. Why is it happening? Default upper bound of T is Any? so i thought it won't be any problem to assign null.

```
class ApiResponse<T> private constructor(
        val data: T, // If I change data type to T?, no error
        val message: String?
) {
    companion object {
        fun <T> OK(): ApiResponse<T> {
            return ApiResponse(null, null)
        }

        fun <T> OK(data: T): ApiResponse<T> {
            return ApiResponse(data, null)
        }
    }
}
```

I've searched with keywords kotlin, generic, constructor, nullable, T but i could not find answer.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
fun <T> OK(): ApiResponse<T> {
   return ApiResponse(null, null)
}
```

if someone calls `ApiResponse.OK<String>()`, then it tries to construct an `ApiResponse` where `data` is null and also of type `String`, which is incompatible.  None of your types prevent that call -- when you have a generic type argument to the function like that, the caller can specify any `T` they please, including a nonnull type.

You must either return an `ApiResponse<T?>`,  or not have an argumentless `OK` factory method.

Comment: I've changed to ApiResponse<T?> and it works. Still i don't get why it is incompatible to construct ApiResponse where data and message is null.

Comment: `T` could be a non-nullable type, which would make your call of `ApiResponse(null, ...)` incompatible because that would be trying to construct an ApiResponse that has a nullable type. For example, this doesn't make sense: `ApiResponse<String>(null, null)`. The type is `String`. `null` is not a `String`. it is a `String?`.

Comment: Consider the following lines of code: `val response = ApiResponse.OK<String>()` `val d: String = response.data`.  In your original code, `response.data` is of type `String`, so this would compile -- but then `d` would be `null` and of type `String`, which is impossible, because `String` isn't nullable, `String?` is.